# maven plugin api: @Paramerter using setters doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am writing a custom maven-plugin for my project. Following the instructions mentioned here
https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#using-setters I added a @Parameter using setters as shown below.

```java
@Parameter(property = "destinationDirectory", defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}/generated-resources")
private String _destinationDirectory;
private Path dstDirRoot;

public void setDestinationDirectory(String destinationDirectory) {
    Path dstDir = Paths.get(destinationDirectory);
    if (dstDir.isAbsolute()) {
         this._destinationDirectory = dstDir.toString();
    } else {
         this._destinationDirectory = Paths.get(baseDir, dstDir.toString()).toString();
    }
    dstDirRoot = Paths.get(this._destinationDirectory);
}
```

Pom.xml entries on the usage side

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.me.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
         <destinationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/myDir</destinationDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, I was expecting that during the plugin execution, it would call `setDestinationDirectory` method. But it doesn't. `@Parameter(property="...")` doesn't seem to have any impact.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `maven-plugin-plugin` version `3.7.0` you can simply add `@Parameter` annotation on public setter methods.

You code can looks like:

```java
@Parameter(...)
public void setDestinationDirectory(String destinationDirectory) {
...
}
```

You also need to define version of `maven-plugin-plugin` and `maven-plugin-annotations` dependency in your `pom.xml` - both should have the same version.

```xml
<project>

<properties>
  <maven-plugin-tools.version>3.7.1</maven-plugin-tools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>${maven-plugin-tools.version</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-plugin-tools.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>help-mojo</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: It worked. Does it mean the Maven documentation is incorrect?

Comment: I think the documentation is correct when using 3.7.1. But the mojo archetype generated the skeleton code with older versions.

Comment: Yes documentation is incorrect - I will fix it also soon :-)

Comment: Does the @Parameter annotation on public setter methods work for collections and array types?

Comment: @Parameter annotation on public setter methods should works for collections and arrays

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, when the annotation has `property = destinationDirectory`, it will read a system property from system properties (e.g. `-D`) or pom properties, unless a configuration section is specified in the XML.

```
mvn generate-resources -DdestinationDirectory=/path/to/dir
```

If a configuration is specified in the XML, which is the case in your example, the name of the configuration will match either the name of the variable or the specified alias, if any. You can try the following options and check if it solves the issue:

**Setting an alias:**

```java
@Parameter(alias = "destinationDirectory", defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}/generated-resources")
private String _destinationDirectory;
```

**Renaming the variable:**

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}/generated-resources")
private String destinationDirectory;
```

It's usually a good practice to keep the name of the configuration and the variables consistent, for easier maintenance.

Comment: This alias suggestions doesn't work. Renaming the variables doesn't the meet requirements in the question.

Comment: Actually the alias suggestion is working after updating the versions as mentioned in Slawomir Jaranowski's post.